# How do I resolve Composer dependency upgrading to CakePHP4?

Tags: cakephp, composer-php, upgrade, cakephp-4.x, cakephp-3.8

I'm following the upgrade instructions for moving a CakePHP project to version 4. All went well until the final command:

> php composer.phar require --update-with-dependencies "cakephp/cakephp:4.0.*"

This resulted in

> Problem 1
>
> > - cakephp/bake 1.11.2 requires cakephp/cakephp ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.8.0, >>3.8.0-RC1, 3.8.0-RC2, 3.8.0-RC3, 3.8.0-beta1, 3.8.1, 3.8.10, 3.8.11, 3.8.2, 3.8.3, 3.8.4, >>3.8.5, 3.8.6, 3.8.7, 3.8.8, 3.8.9, 3.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or >.minimum-stability.
> > - cakephp/bake 1.11.2 requires cakephp/cakephp ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.8.0, 3.8.0-RC1, 3.8.0-RC2, 3.8.0-RC3, 3.8.0-beta1, 3.8.1, 3.8.10, 3.8.11, 3.8.2, 3.8.3, 3.8.4, 3.8.5, 3.8.6, 3.8.7, 3.8.8, 3.8.9, 3.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
> > - cakephp/bake 1.11.2 requires cakephp/cakephp ^3.8.0 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[3.8.0, 3.8.0-RC1, 3.8.0-RC2, 3.8.0-RC3, 3.8.0-beta1, 3.8.1, 3.8.10, 3.8.11, 3.8.2, 3.8.3, 3.8.4, 3.8.5, 3.8.6, 3.8.7, 3.8.8, 3.8.9, 3.x-dev] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
> > - Installation request for cakephp/bake (locked at 1.11.2, required as ^1.9.0) -> satisfiable by cakephp/bake[1.11.2].

The VERSION.txt for the project shows CakePHP at 3.8.11.

In the composer.json file:

```
    "require-dev": {
          "cakephp/bake": "^1.9.0",
           "cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer": "^3.0",
           "cakephp/debug_kit": "^3.17.0",
           "josegonzalez/dotenv": "3.*",
           "psy/psysh": "@stable"
       },
```

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Which parts of that message are unclear?

Comment: A partial update on a major like this is never possible. Always either include all dependencies, or manually fix up your composer and run global "composer update"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without updating, 1) change all requirements according to the latest 4.x [**application template's**](https://github.com/cakephp/app) `composer.json` file, 2) change the requirements for other CakePHP plugins that you might have installed to a 4.x compatible version too, and *then* 3) update your dependencies.

```
composer require --no-update "cakephp/cakephp:^4.0" "cakephp/migrations:^3.0@beta"
composer require --no-update --dev "cakephp/bake:^2.0.3" "cakephp/cakephp-codesniffer:~4.1.0" "cakephp/debug_kit:^4.0" "phpunit/phpunit:^8.5"
composer update --with-dependencies
```

Comment: I still have issues after run these commands: Root composer.json requires admad/cakephp-jwt-auth ^2.4  Root composer.json requires awallef/cakephp-cw-log ^3.4 -> satisfiable by awallef/cakephp-cw-log[3.4.0.0, 3.6.0.0, 3.6.0.1].
    - awallef/cakephp-cw-log[3.4.0.0, ..., 3.6.0.1] require cakephp/cakephp ^3.3 ->

Comment: @R0bertinski Sounds like you skipped at least the second step, neither of those plugin's versions that you're requiring is CakePHP 4 compatible.